# Using idle CPUs to form a cluster for a webserver

Tags: webserver, distributed

This can be a dumb question. I am going to research it more but the folks may give some pointers. 
I have moved countries and work part time at a small but fast growing company that does web applications development. They keep a lot of their work and other applications (bug tracker etc) on a server rented from godaddy.com. That server is now very slow because of the applications running on top of it.
The CEO is reluctant to buy more server CPU until the next six months (cash issues). 
I was wondering if I can find a software or can myself help build a system that can present a cluster of machines as a webserver e.g. some kind of a distrbuted version of IIS. I want to leverage the discarded / old hardware.

I know it is an unconventional query but it has got some real practical value.

Answer (score 4):

Mesos project on github if you are adventurous. It can do cluster and resource management. Check it out. It is vanilla but you can build something using that as it has the right primitives for you :)

--Sai

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should use some kind of workload balancers. I'm not sure if godaddy is able to give you this, but I've seen some "cloud" hosting companies who are able to do it.

So all you'll have to do is to add one more server into your cloud and configure balancer to send some part of the traffic to it.

```
                                +-- WS 1
public IP - Workload balancer --+-- WS 2
                                +-- WS 3
```